# Intermittently receiving StackOverflowError on spring boot restTemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, stack-overflow, resttemplate

Below is the logic that I used for `RestTemplate`. For 1000 requests made, 50 requests fail intermittently. I have to trigger a GET request which sends `List<Students>` in the response. Hence used `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

The logger "Outbound request" displays in the logs and after that I received:`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

The logger "Inbound response" is not displaying.

**Code:**

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public List<Students> getConsents(Long managementid) {

        List<Students> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = buildRequestEntity(managementid);

        ResponseEntity<List<Students>> response = null;

    LOGGER.info("Outbound request");    
        response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Students>>() {});
LOGGER.info("Inbound response");
        if(null != response &&  response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful())
            studentList = response.getBody();

        return studentList;
    }

    private RequestEntity<String> buildRequestEntity(Long managementid) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam("managementid", managementid)
                .build()
                .toUri();
                
        return new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.GET, uri);
    }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at ....
 .....
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:1033)
    ......
```

Please help me if I have used the `RestTemplate` wrong or if you know why I am receiving this error. This occurs in our production environment and I'm not able to reproduce it in our test environment. All the exception handling is done, I just did not paste it here.

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause ? I'm facing similar error.